# Minio bucket failed to copy, Please reduce your request

Tags: kubernetes, storage, gcloud, minio

I'm trying to mirror a minio bucket(70gb of images) to a local machine. while mirroring some images are skipped saying `mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy {url}. Please reduce your request`. Then that particular file is skipped. How can I mirror without skipping any file in the bucket ?

Minio is deployed in kubernetes as a statefulset of 4 nodes.

Minio version : RELEASE.2020-05-08T02-40-49Z

mirror command : ./mc mirror host/bucket backup/

Comment: Did you happen to find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because heavy copying to and from cluster and it was solved by resetting MinIO service.